# Is my UEFI bugged?

Tags: macbook-pro, efi

I just received the new MacBook Pro 15" (with basic configuration).

When I press 'Alt.' during the booting process, I don't see the recovery partition.

Also, the interface is not gray as it used to be on my previous MBPr.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HokHAH2.jpg]

I don't know if this is normal, or if my EFI (I supposed this is the correct component) is bugged. Moreover, during the configuration process (first boot), everything was pretty buggy... (text-inputs wasn't printing what I was typing, the previous configuration step was still printed with the current one [superposition of both], ...)

Am I paranoid or is everything normal?

Comment: When you say, "_I just received the new MacBook Pro 15" (with basic configuration)._", what exactly do you mean?  Did you purchase it from Apple or elsewhere, did it just arrive by shipping to you or someone just handed it to you, etc or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell with the info you posted. Boot to recovery and then enter terminal to check the partition map with `diskutil` (If that doesn't make sense, you can boot to single user mode and use `gpt`)

```
diskutil list disk0

/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

gpt show disk0

     start      size  index  contents
         0         1         PMBR
         1         1         Pri GPT header
         2         4         Pri GPT table
         6     76800      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     76806  61043841      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  61120647    158692      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  61279339         4         Sec GPT table
  61279343         1         Sec GPT header
```

The photo you posted looks proper. You get to recovery now by holding <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> at boot

If you have a larger internal drive, you might also see `gpt` data like:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  488555536      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  488965176    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  490234712          7         
  490234719         32         Sec GPT table
  490234751          1         Sec GPT header
```

Answer (score 1):

That is 100% normal. The latest MacBook Pros have a black background instead of gray. I don't know why Apple chose to make the change, but it's completely normal and not indicative of any problems.

Answer (score 1):

To choose the bootup disk, you need to hold down 'alt' (or option) during the boot-up process. However, this won't show your recovery partition.

To show the recovery partition, you need to hold down <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: alt and option have been the same key for a very long time